# Implementing IList facade, but GetEnumerator returns a count of 0

Tags: c#

I'm a little bit new to programming in .NET, and there's a little bit of a problem that's truly confusing me.

I am trying to implement the `IList<T>` interface in one of my classes. I wanted to keep things simple for now, so I simply used the functionality of a declared `List<T>` field for the methods and added some custom data processing in between.

Most of the methods work well, and the field list gets added to as expected. However, when I try to use the class as a list (e.g. `class.ForEach()`), it returns a `Count` of 0. This is despite the internal `List<T>` having a count of 25.

I'm sure this is really simple, and I apologise if this question is a waste of database space, but it's something that's really holding me back. Can any of you guys help me solve it?

I'll post my current code to show what I'm trying to do:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Reflection;
using ClubEventsData;
using ClubEventsData.Attributes;
using ClubEventsDataHandling.System.Implementations.Conversion;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicModules.Model;

namespace ClubEventsDataHandling.System.Implementations
{
    public class DataRepository<T> : IDataRepository<T> where T : ClubEventData, new()
    {
        private readonly PropertyDictionaryBasedDynamicConverter<T> _converter;
        private readonly IDataHandler _dataHandler;
        private readonly List<T> _storageList;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the DataRepository class.
        /// </summary>
        public DataRepository()
        {
            _dataHandler = new SitefinityBasedDataHandler<T>();
            _converter = new PropertyDictionaryBasedDynamicConverter<T>();
            _storageList = new List<T>();

            // Populate the data repository.
            foreach (DynamicContent dynamicContent in _dataHandler.Get())
            {
                _storageList.Add(_converter.ConvertToModel(dynamicContent));
            }
        }

        #region Implementation of IEnumerable

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns an enumerator that iterates through the collection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// A <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1"/> that can be used to iterate through the collection.
        /// </returns>
        /// <filterpriority>1</filterpriority>
        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _storageList.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Implementation of ICollection<T>

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds an item to the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="item">The object to add to the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.</param><exception cref="T:System.NotSupportedException">The <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> is read-only.</exception>
        public void Add(T item)
        {
            // Create the data item.
            T modelItem = CreateDataItem(item);

            // Add the item to the list.
            _storageList.Add(modelItem);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes all items from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <exception cref="T:System.NotSupportedException">The <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> is read-only. </exception>
        public void Clear()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> contains a specific value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// true if <paramref name="item"/> is found in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>; otherwise, false.
        /// </returns>
        /// <param name="item">The object to locate in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.</param>
        public bool Contains(T item)
        {
            // Determine if the database contains the item.
            return _dataHandler.Get(item.MasterContentID) != null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Copies the elements of the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> to an <see cref="T:System.Array"/>, starting at a particular <see cref="T:System.Array"/> index.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="array">The one-dimensional <see cref="T:System.Array"/> that is the destination of the elements copied from <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>. The <see cref="T:System.Array"/> must have zero-based indexing.</param><param name="arrayIndex">The zero-based index in <paramref name="array"/> at which copying begins.</param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="array"/> is null.</exception><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"><paramref name="arrayIndex"/> is less than 0.</exception><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentException">The number of elements in the source <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> is greater than the available space from <paramref name="arrayIndex"/> to the end of the destination <paramref name="array"/>.</exception>
        public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            _storageList.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes the first occurrence of a specific object from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// true if <paramref name="item"/> was successfully removed from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>; otherwise, false. This method also returns false if <paramref name="item"/> is not found in the original <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.
        /// </returns>
        /// <param name="item">The object to remove from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.</param><exception cref="T:System.NotSupportedException">The <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> is read-only.</exception>
        public bool Remove(T item)
        {
            // Determine if the master content ID has been set.
            ValidateItem(item);

            // Delete the item from the database.
            _dataHandler.Delete(item.MasterContentID);

            // Remove the item from the database.
            return _storageList.Remove(item);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the number of elements contained in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The number of elements contained in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.
        /// </returns>
        public int Count { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> is read-only.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// true if the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> is read-only; otherwise, false.
        /// </returns>
        public bool IsReadOnly { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> contains a specific value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// true if <paramref name="itemID"/>'s item is found in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>; otherwise, false.
        /// </returns>
        /// <param name="itemID">The ID of the object to locate in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.</param>
        public bool Contains(Guid itemID)
        {
            return _dataHandler.Get(itemID) != null;
        }

        ///<summary>Creates the data item in the database and returns the model version of it.</summary>
        private T CreateDataItem(T item)
        {
            // Get the properties of the item.
            Dictionary<string, object> propertyDictionary = GetItemProperties(item);

            // Create the data representation of the item.
            Guid createdItemID = _dataHandler.Create(propertyDictionary);

            // Convert a new model item from the dynamic content.
            DynamicContent dynamicContent = _dataHandler.Get(createdItemID);
            T modelItem = _converter.ConvertToModel(dynamicContent);
            return modelItem;
        }

        ///<summary>Gets the properties of the item as a dictionary that is ready to input into data handler methods.</summary>
        private static Dictionary<string, object> GetItemProperties(T item)
        {
            var propertyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            // Filter  the properties according to the mapping attribute.
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in item.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                // Get the mapping attribute.
                object[] customMappingAttributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (ClubEventDataMappingAttribute), true);
                var mappingAttribute = customMappingAttributes[0] as ClubEventDataMappingAttribute;

                // Apply the action, depending on the mapping attribute.
                if (mappingAttribute != null && mappingAttribute.MappingEnabled)
                {
                    string mappingValue = mappingAttribute.MappingName != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(mappingAttribute.MappingName) ? property.Name : mappingAttribute.MappingName;
                    if (mappingValue != null)
                    {
                        propertyDictionary.Add(mappingValue, property.GetValue(item, null));
                    }
                }

                // Old code, in case didn't work.
                /*if ()
                {
                    propertyDictionary.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(item, null));
                }*/
            }

            return propertyDictionary;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Performs validation operations on the item.
        /// </summary>
        private static void ValidateItem(T item)
        {
            // Check that the ID is present on the item.
            if (item.MasterContentID == Guid.Empty)
            {
                throw new ContentIDNotSetException("The master content ID was not set for this exception.");
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Implementation of IList<T>

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines the index of a specific item in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IList`1"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The index of <paramref name="item"/> if found in the list; otherwise, -1.
        /// </returns>
        /// <param name="item">The object to locate in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IList`1"/>.</param>
        public int IndexOf(T item)
        {
            return _storageList.IndexOf(item);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Inserts an item to the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IList`1"/> at the specified index.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="index">The zero-based index at which <paramref name="item"/> should be inserted.</param><param name="item">The object to insert into the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IList`1"/>.</param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"><paramref name="index"/> is not a valid index in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IList`1"/>.</exception><exception cref="T:System.NotSupportedException">The <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IList`1"/> is read-only.</exception>
        public void Insert(int index, T item)
        {
            // Create a new data item based off the properties of this one.
            T modelItem = CreateDataItem(item);

            // Insert the model item into the list.
            _storageList.Insert(index, modelItem);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IList`1"/> item at the specified index.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="index">The zero-based index of the item to remove.</param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"><paramref name="index"/> is not a valid index in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IList`1"/>.</exception><exception cref="T:System.NotSupportedException">The <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IList`1"/> is read-only.</exception>
        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            // Get the item at the index.
            T item = this[index];

            // Validate the item ID.
            ValidateItem(item);

            // Delete the item from the database.
            _dataHandler.Delete(item.MasterContentID);

            // Remove the item from the list.
            _storageList.RemoveAt(index);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the element at the specified index.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The element at the specified index.
        /// </returns>
        /// <param name="index">The zero-based index of the element to get or set.</param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"><paramref name="index"/> is not a valid index in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IList`1"/>.</exception><exception cref="T:System.NotSupportedException">The property is set and the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IList`1"/> is read-only.</exception>
        public T this[int index]
        {
            get { return _storageList[index]; }
            set
            {
                // Validate the specified content ID.
                ValidateItem(value);

                // Update the database instance with the item properties.
                _dataHandler.Update(value.MasterContentID, GetItemProperties(value));

                // Reflect the changes in the list.
                _storageList[index] = value;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Implementation of IEnumerable

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns an enumerator that iterates through a collection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// An <see cref="T:System.Collections.IEnumerator"/> object that can be used to iterate through the collection.
        /// </returns>
        /// <filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

And here is the method I use to call the repository:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ClubEventsData;
using System.Linq;
using System;

namespace ClubEventsDataHandling.System.Implementations.Controllers
{
    public class TicketDataController : IDataController
    {
        private DataRepository<Ticket> _repository;

        public TicketDataController()
        {
            _repository = new DataRepository<Ticket>();
        }

        public List<Ticket> GetDateTickets(Guid dateID)
        {
            return _repository.Where(ticket => ticket.EventDateBoughtFor.MasterContentID == dateID).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for `_repository.Count` being 0 is simply that you don't access your `_storageList` in the `Count` property. You need to change it to this:

```
public int Count
{ 
    get { return _storageList.Count; }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I guess it really  was that simple. Thanks.